# Programmatically close Preference Header

Tags: android

In my application I am displaying [Preference Headers in the recommended way](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#PreferenceHeaders).

I extend [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) and add the headers from the XML resource as so:

```
@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preference_headers, target);
}
```

One such Header is:

```
<header
    android:fragment="com.example.FragmentSettings"
    android:summary="Tap to configure"
    android:title="General Settings" />
```

Which launches the main Preference Fragment which extends [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html)

A particular Setting allows a user to wipe all of the data the application has access to and deauthorise their account.

If the user selects this option, I wipe everything, cache, shared preferences etc etc and I would then like to return them to the initial authorisation screen.

The problem is that the Preference Header Screen persists, even when all Activities call `finish();` and even if I call `System.exit(0);`

How can I make the damn thing close!?

Help!

Comment: _This question has not received enough attention_ --- probably, the reason it that this is a very specific case and you should have added minimal working code that demonstrates your case.

Answer (score 0):

Given the small amount of detail you've given, I'll try to provide an answer assuming you want the activity backstack cleared when you open the authorisation screen.

- MyPreferenceActivity - only 'onBuildHeaders' as an example (also, the activity is opened when a button is clicked)
- preference-headers - only 'FragmentSettings'

FragmentSettings:

```
public class FragmentSettings extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_settings);

        Preference myPref = (Preference) findPreference("pref_clearAllData");
        myPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(FragmentSettings.this.getActivity(), AuthActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
                    startActivity(intent);

                    return true;
                }
            });
    }
}
```

preference_settings (I'm assuming you're not using a checkbox, but it works as an example):

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<PreferenceCategory android:title="General Settings" >
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="pref_clearAllData"
        android:title="Clear all data"
        android:summary="Clears all data and shows the authorisation screen"
        android:defaultValue="false" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Answer (score -1):

please try this:

```
protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: While this might work, a little explanation will go a long way to understand why.

Comment: Please explain why this code works. This avoids copying and pasting without understanding.

Comment: Please can you explain what this would achieve?